# Error debugging - Conversion from String to Double

Tags: vb.net, debugging, error-handling

I'm doing some error debugging trying to get the errors on our website down to a minimum and there seems to be an error that is popping up quite a lot

> Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

I'm unable to replicate this problem but I can see that it is happening.

I've been looking through the code in one of the pages and strolled across this

```
Dim varWeek As String

If varWeek < 10 Then
    'Do something'
End If
```

Could this be causing the problem as it is trying to see if a `String` is less than `10` which is an `Integer`?

As I said before as I am unable to see this error in the first place so changing this to an `Integer` doesn't change anything on my system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot see any reason as to why this conversion should result in a double.
Most likely you have some operation where a double should fit.

In general, I would use conversions before attempting operations, e.g.:

```
If Convert.ToInt32( varWeek ) < 10 Then
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered yourself.

Try converting that String variable to integer. For example use:

```
Dim varWeek As String

If Val(varWeek) < 10 Then
'Do something
End If
```

I'm not sure if you already tried, but did you use the Try Catch statement? That way you could see where is the error coming from.

Debug on buddy ;)

Comment: I'm not really sure when to use Try Catch statements - I use them for when I'm running queries mainly.

Answer (score 1):

The error is being caused because your string is empty "".

You should do some kind of error checking on the string before comparing it to a number.

You could do something like this:

```
Dim varWeek As String
If IsNumeric(varWeek)
   If varWeek < 10 Then
      Do something
   End If
Else
   Handle your error here, probably feed back to the user that their input is invalid
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If your message is the exception's message, it's a convertion failure.
If you pass a empty string (your "") to Convert.ToDouble, Double.Parse (in C#), it launch an FormatException.

You can avoid this using [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx).